# Multiple Input (Window Method) in CTNKTextFromatReader for the DNN model

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, cntk, brainscript

I use the Brainscript CNTK for training a DNN model. I use CNTKTextFormatReader. The problem is I need future and past data in one input sequence. There are a lot of methods for LMSequenceReader and HTKMLF readers. For instance word context and windows can be used or LookupTableOrder. However, I cannot make it work for the CNTKTextFormatReader. So can you suggest any method for CNTKTextFromatReader?